# Displaying UIViewController, NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, performance, nsoperation

I have been on an iOS 5 app in which I have an NSOperationQueue which works fine to get some data and create a UIViewController. However, at one point when every operation seems to be complete the app is unresponsive for quite a long time. Here's how it goes:

1. Get some data from DB
2. Queue - For each item Init a custom UIViewController object.
3. Hand each UIViewController object over to the MainViewController and display them.

Everything goes fine until the UIVC objects have to appear. 
It goes past all the [[self view] addSubview:object.view]; and to the end of the function. 
But then there is a huge lag, from 5 to 30 seconds before the NSLog statements inside the viewDidApear of the UIVC object show up...

So in code:

```
//MainViewController
-(void)displayNewView {
  [[self view] addSubview:object.view];
  NSLog(@"Done setup");
}

//-- Long unresponsiveness --//

//UIVC object
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  NSLog(@"Start appear");
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

What could be causing this? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In my experience, the act of adding an operation to the operation queue seems to cause a delay. I started using performSelectorInBackground instead.

Comment: I would not create UIViewController instances and add subview in a background thread. Get the data in background, but work with UI elements in the main thread.

Comment: @jerrylroberts - Yea but performSelectorInBackground meant I had to add NSAutoreleasePools and its not as clean as queues...

Comment: @Davyd - Well I create the UIViewControllers in the background but I think I do addSubview: on mainThread, I will check and make sure it does so... THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was the complexity of each UIViewController that delayed the whole process.

To me they seem simple but I guess the iPhone doesn't like creating 10 views at a time with several buttons, labels and images. 
Simplifying the nib and making sure only what is used is allocated and initialized helped a lot.. but its still not perfectly fluid.